# C++ Getting data from a dialogbox

Tags: winapi, dialog

I have made a simple win32 application, that opens a dialog box with an edit control. After searching for hours I couldn't find a way to get the user input from this edit control and store it in a string. I think the code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31315/Getting-User-Input-With-Dialogs-Part-1) does what I want (haven't tested it) but I don't understand any of it. So an explanation or other solution would be nice. (I'm using VC++ 2012)

Other [solution](http://www.davekb.com/browse_programming_tips%3adialog_box_param%3atxt) I found that IS C++ :S

Ok, I made a seperate message loop, and inserted the code there. Which now looks like this:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK IP(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        else if(LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK)
        {
            TCHAR szBuf[40];
            GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDIT1, szBuf, 39);
              //Breakpoint here!
              //szBuf="127.0.0.1" as intended :)
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Comment: No wonder you don't understand the article, it solves the problem using C#, not C++. Look for a C++ solution

Comment: I can only imagine your confusion with the linked page might have something to do with the fact that it is C#, not C++. So what code have *you* tried? Post that, with specific questions on what appears to *not* be working as you expect. Did you try [this](http://bit.ly/144FW43) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use

```
UINT WINAPI GetDlgItemText(
  _In_   HWND hDlg,
  _In_   int nIDDlgItem,
  _Out_  LPTSTR lpString,
  _In_   int nMaxCount
);
```

like this:

```
TCHAR szBuf[BUFF_LEN];
GetDlgItemText(hWnd, TXT_MYEDIT_ID, szBuf, BUFF_LEN - 1);
```

Comment: `sizeof(szBuf)` is a bad idea when TCHAR is wide (as it is with Unicode, the default charset in VS2010 and beyond), and even worse if it isn't an automatic array. Use the WIN32-provided macro `_countof()` if using an automatic array, or specify the actual buffer size in TCHAR's if it is a dynamic buffer.